# Inserting variable into MYSQL from a form that contain variables

Tags: php, mysql

Okay so I have a form and php file that sends the form data to MYSQL.
I understand that my SQL command interprets apostrophes as a closing syntax or something and won't insert them.
However I have a string replace for all apostrophes. This seemed to work until I inserted the variables into html and tried inserthing them again.
See below

```
$c1=$_POST['c1'];
$c1a=str_replace("'", "''", "$c1");

$report= '
<html>
<body>
<p align=\”left\”><strong>Comments:</strong></p>
    <p align=\”left\”>
    '.$c1a.'
      <br>
    </p></td><html> ';
```

When I try to insert $report into my sql it won't let it go, as if the string replace never took place. But I know it did because when I echo $report to test it, all the apostrophes are replaced. What's going on!

Also, I have tested multiple times and the insert works when my form data doesn't include an apostrophe.

Comment: What is the database field defined as? VARCHAR?

What does the SQL insertion code in the PHP script look like?

Comment: `”` are not valid quotes for html anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add backslashes before single quotes. You can use the function mysql_real_escape_string() (or mysqli_real_escape_string()) to do that.